# Show java package interface in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to show the public interface of a package in eclipse? With public interface i mean everything which can be seen outside the package like public classes/interfaces and public/protected class members.

I guess that this is not generally possible, as packages can be extended anywhere but i would be happy to see the interface just for predefined source directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see this in eclipse directly. But you could generate JavaDoc for your project (`Project` -> `Generate Javadoc`) and set the member visibility to Public.